# Sending commands to running python progress

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, tcpserver

I want to communicate from a server to clients with a TCP server. My question regarding this is what I would do (resp. what would be a common method) to send bytes to a client from a different thread, e.g. when someone calls up a python script from the web. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your needs ? If your clients connects to your server using a browser, then you might want to use [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/). If you already have developed some code using threads, then please provide some sample of it so we can help you.

Comment: I don't know how I could be more specific, explained again: I want to develop a TCP server in python (which is pretty easy). This server resp. the thread it runs in should be informed about other processes, e.g. somebody calling up a different script on the server using http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a member variable for the threads created when a client is connected. Then use a lock to write into this variable. This variable will be shared by all threads :

```
import threading

class ConnectedClients(threading.Thread):

    used_ressources = list()
    used_ressources_lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self, ressource_to_get):
        if ressource_to_get in used_ressources:
            raise Exception('Already used ressource:' + repr(ressource_to_get))
        else:
            can_access = self.used_ressources_lock.acquire(blocking=True, timeout=5)
            if can_access:
                self.used_ressources.append(ressource_to_get)
                self.used_ressources_lock.release()
                # Do something...
                # You will have to acquire lock and remove ressource from
                # the list when you're done with it.
            else:
                raise Exception("Cannot acquire lock")
```

Is something like this that you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, thanks a lot!Anyway, I will now use Objective-C for the Servers, cause it is more reliable and much easier to control, there are more librarys, server and client in same language, etc.